# Unity3d graphic issue on build

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics

So my game is working great on the editor and when build (On my pc) once i sent my game to a friend (he's computer is low-mid end pc) he got this weird bug

[image]
for some reason some textures are "ok" and some is just weird black and white

Comment: Is this build working correctly on high resolution ?

Comment: A bit of a long shot, but are you using any compute shaders in the problematic textures?

Comment: How do you `send it` to him? Is it a Standalone (.exe) build? Are you using static lightning?